# Does some optimized web servers for single page application exists?

Tags: ajax, web-applications, websocket

When we do single page application, the webserver basically does only one things, it gives some data when the client asks them (using JSON format for example). So any server side language (php, ror) or tool (apache, ningx) can do it.

But is there a language/tool that works better with this sorts of single page applications that generates lot of small requests that need low latency and sometimes permanent connection (for realtime and push things)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a lot of small requests in realtime by pushing data - you should take a look at socket type connections.

Check out [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) with [Socket.io](http://socket.io).

Comment: http://teddziuba.com/2011/10/node-js-is-cancer.html make me wonder how node.js can scale well.

Comment: It's pretty clear that Ted has a fundamental problem with Javascript on the server. What he fails to address is that Javascript developers are already quite familiar with writing event driven applications. Yes, Node.js (and Javascript in the browser for that matter) will suck if you are doing expensive computation in your main thread. As long as you avoid that, Node.js is REALLY fast: http://zgadzaj.com/benchmarking-nodejs-basic-performance-tests-against-apache-php

Answer (score 2):

[SocketStream](https://github.com/socketstream/socketstream) seems like it matches your requirements quite well: "A phenomenally fast real-time web framework for Node.js ... dedicated to creating single-page real time websites."

SocketStream uses WebSockets to get lowest latency for the real-time portion. There are several examples on the site to build from.

Comment: thx, i'll compare with socket.io that seems to handle very well "websocket"

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to optimize for speed, you could try implementing a custom HTTP server that just fits your needs, for example with the help of [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty).
It's blazingly fast and has examples for HTTP and WebSocket servers included.

Also, taking a look at [GWAN](http://www.trustleap.com/) may be worthwile (though I have not tried that one yet).

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx could be [appropriate](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2011/11/a-faster-web-server-ripping-out-apache-for-nginx.ars)